# Ler ficheiro txt para Select

Tags: php

Quero utilizar um `select`, com os dados que estão dentro de um ficheiro `.txt`, criado por mim. Utilizar uma função em PHP. Dentro do ficheiro (`select.txt`) tenho:

```
teste1 
teste2 
teste3
```

E o `select`

```
<select name=select >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tente explicar um bocadinho melhor a pergunta para que fique mais percetível para ajudar outros utilizadores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para poucos registros pode usar a função [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), ela carrega todo o arquivo e converter as linhas do em array.

```
<?php $linhas = file('teste.txt'); ?>
<select name=select >
    <?php foreach($linhas as $item){ ?>
           <option value=""><?php echo $item; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Outra forma de ler um arquivo é combinando as funções [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) para abrir o arquivo e [fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) extrai o conteudo o segundo argumento da função opcional informa a quantia de bytes que devem ser lidos.

```
<?php $arquivo = fopen('teste.txt', 'r'); ?>
<select name=select >
    <?php while($linha = fgets($arquivo)){ ?>
           <option value=""><?php echo $linha; ?></option>
    <?php }
      fclose($arquivo);
     ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Esta resposta salvou a pergunta +1

Answer (score 6):

A forma mais fácil de se fazer é utilizando a função [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), ela lê o arquivo e retorna um `array` contendo para cada posição, uma linha do arquivo lido.

Dessa forma você conseguirá ler cada linha do arquivo e imprimir as options dentro do select.

```
<select name='select'>
  <?php
    $arquivo = file("arquivo.txt");
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arquivo); $i++) {
      print "<option value=''>". $arquivo[$i] ."</option>";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Para selecionar uma única linha do arquivo use:

(Lembrando que em arrays a primeira posição é 0)

```
print $arquivo[1]."<br>";
```

> Retirado desse [link](http://www.codigosnaweb.com/forum/Ler-arquivo-txt-linha-por-linha_1_1434.html)

Answer (score 5):

Use o fopen para poder ler o arquivo txt linha por linha em um array [aqui temos um tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp). O ideal acredito que você tenha que jogar em um array ou algo do tipo para poder ler separadamente, mais para deixar o código bonito, como está [aqui](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p7.html).

Depois você pode pegar essa variável e realizar um foreach dentro do seu select:

```
foreach($variavel as $linhas)
{
 $select = "<option value=''>".$linhas."</option>";
}
```